# Hyper-V Server with Wireless as main connection

Tags: hyper-v

I'm testing out different Hypervisors in my home lab, and currently I only have wifi available. I've managed to get the drivers installed for my wireless card, but I can't seem to connect to a network now.

I know you can usually use `netsh wlan ...` but this seems to be stripped from the Hyper-V Server installation.

Any suggestions? Please keep in mind, this is Hyper-V Server 2012, not Windows Server 2012 with a Hyper-V role.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your wifi connection with ipconfig /all, check for DNS servers and take note.
2. Edit your Wifi adapter and set a static IP and enter DNS values from step 1 for allways have internet connnection
3. Now you can créate a Virtual Switch (External) with your WiFi Adapter
4. Create you VM with Hyper-V, assign the external switch and check, you have internet in your machine (host) and the VM.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but you've driven past the same issue that most other articles do. "Edit your Wifi adapter". This is an easy task when you have a GUI, or the wlan features of netsh. When you're using Hyper-V Server, you don't have these options.